# isset function not working correctly

Tags: php

I am trying to insert records into a table but I am facing a problem on the `isset` function. I am unable to process the code.

In the following code the else statement is executed instead of the isset function.

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['firstname']);
    $surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['surname']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
    $cpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cpassword']);
    $bdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['bdate']);
    $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['gender']);

    if(empty($firstname) || empty($surname) || empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($cpassword) || empty($bdate) || empty($gender)) {
       header("Location: ../index.php?index=empty");
       exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?index=username already taken");
            exit();
        } else {
            // Hashing the password
            $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            //Insert users into the database
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, firstname, surname, email, username, password, bdate, gender) VALUES ('', '$firstname', '$surname', '$email', '$username', '$password', '$bdate', '$gender');";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            header("Location: ../profile.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?index=error");
    exit();
}
```

Here is the front-end containing the "sign up" part:

```
<div class="container and">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 pull-right">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3>Create a new account.</h3>
  </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
     <form id="loginform" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="POST">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="form-group has-error col-md-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group has-error col-md-6">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" placeholder="Surname">
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row padding-top-10">
                    <div class="form-group has-error col-md-12">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                    </div>
        </div>
       <div class="row padding-top-10">
         <div class="form-group has-error col-md-12">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
         </div>
       </div>
         <div class="row padding-top-10">
           <div class="form-group has-error col-md-12 padding-top-10">
             <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
           </div>
         </div>
           <div class="row padding-top-10">
             <div class="form-group has-error col-md-12">
               <input type="password" class="form-control" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
             </div>
           </div>
         <div class="row padding-top-10">
           <div class="form-group has-error col-md-12">
             <h4>&nbsp;&nbsp; Birthday</h4>
             <input type="date" class="form-control" name="bdate" value="birthdate">
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row padding-top-10">
           <div class="form-group has-error col-md-6 padding-top-10">
             <div class="pull-right">
            Male: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />
           </div>
           </div>
           <div class=" form-group has-error col-md-6 padding-top-10">
             Female: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="padding-top-10">
         <button class="btn btn-success" name="submit">Create Account</button>
       </div>
     </form>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you done `var_dump($_POST);` to confirm that submit is in the POST global?

Comment: Clearly `$_POST['submit']` is not set. And I know this nitpicking, but `isset` is a language construct, not a function.

Comment: Seeing that the `input` with name `"submit"` is a standard `button` and not a `type="submit"`, this suggests javascript somewhere is handling the form submit event (either ajax, or directly). Due to that, that value won't be included in the POST args. You would need to check on something that would be sent. A hidden form field with a value would work, or add an arg and value with the javascript action. Otherwise, question is too vague with missing code.

Comment: are you sure set the correct address php file in form.I mean here.<form id="loginform" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="POST">

Comment: Don't rely on `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to prevent SQL injection, [it alone is not sufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string). You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: Try  `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit">`

Comment: Thanks for your comments I will edit the code as said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the button type attribute which will be `type="submit"` If you didn't include this type attribute, the form will not submit data.

**Your code:**

`<button class="btn btn-success" name="submit">Create Account</button>`

**It should be:**

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit">Create Account</button>`

If, this is not your problem, let me know! Thanks.

Comment: "Note: If you use the `<button>` element in an HTML form, different browsers may submit different values. Use `<input>` to create buttons in an HTML form" : `<input type="submit" ...>...</input>`.

Comment: @gangesh make sure you specify the correct **action url** and just before checking the if isset submit condition. Just use **var_dump($_POST);** to check whether you getting the submit post data. Keep me updated, after checking this. :)

Comment: @Anbuselvan Rocky the action url is correct. As I am new to php please tell me where to put var_dump($_POST); thanks

Comment: @gangesh Insert **var_dump($_POST);** just before `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` line of code.

Comment: @Anbuselvan Rocky nothing happened with this the block executes the else statement of the if (isset). after deleting the error message in else part it game me this output   array(0) { }

Comment: Let me have a look at your full source code. Facebook me the full code to fb.me/anburocky3 Thanks.